# Diagrams of TeX Design

Tags: tex-core, sourcecode

In order to understand TeX better, and in order to procrastinate on stuff that is almost certainly more important, I'm slowly working my way through a [YouTube series of Knuth explaining TeX82 internals](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5B7B2302476634D5) and *TeX: The Program* (which I think describes TeX3).

I'm following it all… more or less. But it's too much to keep in my head, and (literate programming or not) I'm finding text to be a less-than-ideal format for getting a bigger picture of the code.

Is there somewhere a set of diagrams of the major elements of TeX's design—e.g. data structures, flow charts, state machines?

Comment: Most diagrams that I have seen about TeX\LaTeX are the flow of file generation like [this](http://math.nie.edu.sg/kcang/latex/flow02.gif) that mostly are out outdated (actually hardly you will need obtain a `.pdf` through a  `.dvi` or `.ps` file conversion). May for another issues is simply of little utility.